# Дан файл, который содержит в себе натуральные числа, по одному в строке. Найдите наибольшее из всех чисел файла

Tags: python, строки, файлы, числа

Задание от репетитора, не знаю как его сделать, вот что имею:

```py
f = open("8.2.txt")
s = f.readline()
maximum = 0
```

Comment: Ну по логике прочитать все строки, перевести каждую строку в число, сравнить с максимумом. Что из этого не получается? Хелпы для открытия файлов обычно включают и примеры для чтения всего содержимого

Comment: Помощь наводящая: что содержит переменная s?

Answer (score 2):

Покажу вам примерный шаблон для вашего решения:

```py
maximum = 0
with open("8.2.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # тут нужно сделать из строки line число
        # тут нужно сравнить это число с maximum
        # если число больше maximum, то теперь maximum - это число из файла

# напечатать maximum
```